# Create your own tags/functions with Erubis

Tags: ruby, templates, eruby, erubis

I have a ruby class that extends Erubis (a ruby templating engine) and I would like to create my own tags. The following is an example of what i'd like to be reproduce:

```
<%= link_to "/some/url" %>
```

This code should generate a html 'a' tag linking to some url. Now i'd like to be able to create my own tags such as:

```
<%= javascript_file "/some/javascript/file" %>
```

which would generate a script tag linking to some javascript file of my choice.

How can i easily extend erubis to do that?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are just function calls that return the tag in a string:

```
def javascript_file( file_path )
    "<script src=\"#{ file_path }\" type=\"text/javascript\"/>"
 end
```

You just need to ensure that the functions are within scope at the time you call the binding.

Comment: i only realised this morning that my problem came from using the evaluate() function of Erubis. Using binding() solved the issue.